# Segmentation Fault freeing a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, vector

i get a segmentation fault error compiling the code below. this comes from the desctructor implementation when i try to free the vector of pointers. Could you please help?

I also have another question. For me i think i can only delete the pointers inside the vector, and the vector will be deleted automatically. but is it possible that the vector will hold nothing when the pointers are deleted? thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

/* ******************************************************* Node ********************************************************* */

template<class T>
class Node
{
    private:
        T _value;
        vector<Node<T>*> children;

    public:
        Node(T value);
        Node(const Node<T>& node);
        void AddChild(Node<T>* node);
        T getValue() const;
        vector<Node<T>*> returnChildren() const;
        ~Node();
};

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T value):_value(value)
{
    children.push_back(NULL);
}

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node& node):_value(node.getValue()), 
                                children(node.returnChildren())
{
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::AddChild(Node* node)
{
    if (children[0]==NULL){children.pop_back();};
    children.push_back(node);
}

template <class T>
T Node<T>::getValue() const
{
    return _value;
}

template <class T>
vector<Node<T>*> Node<T>::returnChildren() const
{
    return children;
}

template <class T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    for (typename vector<Node<T>*>::iterator it=children.begin() ; it!=children.end() ; it++)
    {
        delete *it;
    }
}



int main()
{
    Node<int> n(3);
    Node<int> nn(4);
    n.AddChild(&nn);
    Node<int>* child= new Node<int>(*(n.returnChildren()[0]));
    cout << (*child).getValue() << endl;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `delete` on a pointer to an object on the stack. What do you think will happen?

Comment: Oh yes, i created nn on the stack. i just created it with new and it works. thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO There are basically two errors:
1) in ~Node() you should add the check to see if the pointer to the child is null (otherwise deleting a null pointer cause the seg fault)
2) instantiating in the main function nodes as local variable (in the stack of the function and not in the heap) will automatically launch the ~Node() at the exiting of the function: this means another seg fault because you're trying to delete twice the same pointer.

Comment: 1) is incorrect. Deleting null does not cause a seg fault.

Comment: 2) is an accurate identification of the problem, but "delete twice" is not an accurate description.  Calling delete with the address of a local variable once is already enough for a seg fault.